# How to disable host LRO/CSUM on Host running Virtual Box

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtio

Running Oracle VirtualBox Version 5.2.18 on Windows 7. 
Virtual Machine with Fedora 30.1.2 is created. Linux Kernel is 5.1.0.
Network Adapter configured in Virtual Box for this VM is Paravirtualised network (virtio-net).

When I try to load xdp eBPF program onto the interface, it fails.

[root@localhost bpf]#  ip link set dev enp0s10 xdpdrv obj xdp_ip_filter_kern.o sec xdp_ip_filter
Error: virtio_net: Can't set XDP while host is implementing LRO/CSUM, disable LRO/CSUM first.
[root@localhost bpf]#

I tried to turn of LRO and CSUM using ethtool from inside Linux VM, but they are fixed, and unable to turn off.

[root@localhost ~]# ethtool --show-offload enp0s10 | egrep 'summing|large'
rx-checksumming: on [fixed]
tx-checksumming: on
large-receive-offload: on [fixed]
[root@localhost ~]#

The question I have is
How do I disable host LRO/CSUM ?
Should I change any configuration on the Windows Host ? or, Is there any configuration on the VirtualBox that would disable host LRO/CSUM ?

Any guidance is much appreciated.